# .xccheckout files in command line

Tags: xcode, git, jenkins

Since XCode - I'd say XCode 5 but I'm not sure - XCode maintains inside xcworkspace a xccheckout file that hold information about all the git repositories inside a project.

And that is great. I believe that OS X Server continuous integration bots use it to pull repositories before building. Which is also great.

The only thing is... I'm using jenkins for my builds.

Does any one know if there is a way to read these xccheckout files and pull all the repositories at the proper location, and all that from command line ? So that I can script it, before building my workspace.

Here is a typicall xccheckout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>IDESourceControlProjectFavoriteDictionaryKey</key>
  <false/>
  <key>IDESourceControlProjectIdentifier</key>
  <string>EF087A90-0B8C-4247-BD67-C07C71A3C34C</string>
  <key>IDESourceControlProjectName</key>
  <string>testproject</string>
  <key>IDESourceControlProjectOriginsDictionary</key>
  <dict>
    <key>4169309C54D8E435F84287928B9751B894920C41</key>
    <string>ssh://gitlab.test/libraries/firstLib.git</string>
    <key>94C8B3A5277B40CCD5E9739E5D105F1D70E9B323</key>
    <string>ssh://gitlab.test/libraries/secondLib.git</string>
  </dict>
  <key>IDESourceControlProjectPath</key>
  <string>kfcloyalty.xcworkspace</string>
  <key>IDESourceControlProjectRelativeInstallPathDictionary</key>
  <dict>
    <key>4169309C54D8E435F84287928B9751B894920C41</key>
    <string>../../libraries/firstLib</string>
    <key>94C8B3A5277B40CCD5E9739E5D105F1D70E9B323</key>
    <string>../../libraries/secondLib</string>
    <string>..</string>
  </dict>
  <key>IDESourceControlProjectURL</key>
  <string>ssh://gitlab.test/testproject.git</string>
  <key>IDESourceControlProjectVersion</key>
  <integer>111</integer>
  <key>IDESourceControlProjectWCCIdentifier</key>
  <string>D37710F4A624D737F25B20742E20352D45226453</string>
  <key>IDESourceControlProjectWCConfigurations</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>IDESourceControlRepositoryExtensionIdentifierKey</key>
      <string>public.vcs.git</string>
      <key>IDESourceControlWCCIdentifierKey</key>
      <string>4169309C54D8E435F84287928B9751B894920C41</string>
      <key>IDESourceControlWCCName</key>
      <string>firstLib</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>IDESourceControlRepositoryExtensionIdentifierKey</key>
      <string>public.vcs.git</string>
      <key>IDESourceControlWCCIdentifierKey</key>
      <string>94C8B3A5277B40CCD5E9739E5D105F1D70E9B323</string>
      <key>IDESourceControlWCCName</key>
      <string>secondLib</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>IDESourceControlRepositoryExtensionIdentifierKey</key>
      <string>public.vcs.git</string>
      <key>IDESourceControlWCCIdentifierKey</key>
      <string>D37710F4A624D737F25B20742E20352D45226453</string>
      <key>IDESourceControlWCCName</key>
      <string>testProject</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue in reading the content when you already know the location of the file?

Comment: You mean, like parsing myself the plist files?

Comment: Exactly! Can you just paste the content here?

Comment: I could but it would be troublesome. I'm hopping there is a command line call with xcodebuild or something that I missed to make it easier... Anyway I'm updating the question with a content

Comment: Are you interested in only the ones that have `ssh://` in the above file?

Comment: What I want is more like : the two libraries have relative path. I want to pull them both, and put them in their relative path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60539/discussion-between-technext-and-redwarp).

Comment: I'm wondering how to do this as well. Xcodebuild doesn't seem to respect or attempt to checkout remote dependencies that are added (and referenced in) the .xccheckout file.

Comment: @AndrewTheis I haven't find a solution (apart from writing a parser myself), so I reorganized my project so that dependencies are git submodules, and well... I just check them out recursively on Jenkins before building.